# How to redirect water pooling behind skylights

Tags: roof, waterproofing, drainage, roofing, skylight

I have a pair of skylights in my roof that leak every time it rains. I've tried silicone and a roofing sealant along the edges.. still leaks. During the last storm heavy rain I went up to check it out and I noticed that the water is pooling behind these.

Any ideas on how to redirect this water?

[image]

Comment: Even with water pooling they should not leak....